# Using SQL COUNT(*) and Only Return Results with Valid Count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a student table with columns:

student_name | Email | teacher_id | teacher_name

The goal is to count the number of students each teacher has.

```
SELECT teacher_id, COUNT(*) AS active_students
FROM students
GROUP BY teacher_id;
```

Using the above SQL, I am able to get the number of counts for each teacher ID.
However, when I include the teacher_name, I will get an error. Each student may have the same teacher_id if they share the same teacher and some students have NULL teacher_id if they did not register for a class.

How do I change my query so that I can count the number of students each teacher_id has and also include other columns on the same table?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the teach id and name in the table.  You should have a separate table for teachers.

Comment: Is teacher name in the same table?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the teacher name to both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses:

```
SELECT teacher_id, teacher_name, COUNT(*) AS active_students
FROM students
GROUP BY teacher_id, teacher_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the same `teacher_id` always has the same `teacher_name` (pointing to fact the table probably should be further normalized), you could just add it to the `group by` clause:

```sql
SELECT   teacher_id, teacher_name, COUNT(*) AS active_students
FROM     students
GROUP BY teacher_id, teacher_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the columns along with a count, use window functions:

```
SELECT s.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY teacher_id) AS active_students
FROM students s;
```

More likely, though, you want more information about the *teachers* and there is a separate table for teachers.  In that case, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from students s
        where s.teacher_id = t.teacher_id
       ) as num_students
from teachers t;
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### For all record of table:-

```
 SELECT A.*,COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY TEACHER_ID ORDER BY TEACHER_ID ) STUDENT_NUMBERS FROM STUDENT AS A;
```

---

### For selected record of table:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.TEACHER_ID,TEACHER_NAME,COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY TEACHER_ID ORDER BY TEACHER_ID ) STUDENT_NUMBERS FROM STUDENT AS A;
```

It may help you:-
[You can check with attached demo link: **CLICK HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=595a8e832378b6b77c0f0950917d5ee9)